# Eclipse can't open any xml layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to open an xml in my eclipse.
The xml doesn't show correctly. Any one know how can I fix the problem?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting Eclipse?

Comment: Install Android Studio and forget about Eclipse :)

Comment: I am already using Android studio. But that's an old project and the client want that we keep using Eclipse for that project.